# Java : JPanel GridBagLayout issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I'm making a program in which `JPanel` has two components `JTextField` and `JLabel`.And that `JPanel` using `GridBadLayout`
in it.And i make a method for `GridBagConstraints` which add components in it.But that method does not Work with
`JPanel` instance.But Working With `JFrame`.I want to fix this method with `JPanel` but don't know how to do it.
Code:

```
public class A extends JFrame {

    private final GridBagLayout layout;

    private final GridBagConstraints gbc;

    private JPanel p;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JTextField field1;

    public A() {

        super("Frame");

        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(layout);
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        label1 = new JLabel("Enter Name");
        p.addConstraints(label1);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        field1 = new JTextField(15);

        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    // Method for GridBag Component Constraints
    private void addConstraints(Component com) {

        layout.setConstraints(com, gbc);
        add(com);

    }
```

Main Method

```
public class MainMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A frame = new A();

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

`add(com);`
adds the component to 'this', which is the JFrame, not the JPanel. Also, there's already an `addConstraints` method provided in Java, `add(Component comp, Object constraints)`.

Instead of using your addConstraints method, you could try this:

```
p.add(label1, gbc);
```

Next to that I'm missing a `this.add(p);`.

Edit:

If you want to just call `addConstraints(Component comp)` update the method to this:

```
// Method for GridBag Component Constraints
private void addConstraints(Component com) {
    p.add(com, gbc);
}
```

This way, the constructor can look like the following:

```
public A() {
    super("Frame");

    p = new JPanel();
    this.add(p);
    p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridy = 0;
    label1 = new JLabel("Enter Name");
    addConstraints(label1);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    field1 = new JTextField(15);
    addConstraints(field1);

    setSize(300, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I know i can do that with this way  but is there a way that i can improve my method to work with panel

Comment: `p.add(label1, gbc);` is working with JPanel. If you want that inside your `addConstraints` method, simply replace the current content for `p.add(com, gbc);`. Now you can call it in the constructor like this: `addConstraints(label1);`

Comment: could you please replace your answer with that

Comment: @JohnDoe Added that to the answer, and slightly changed the content of the constructor to be more readable (at least in my opinion).